# Parsing content of brackets in rust proc_macro

Tags: rust, rust-macros, rust-proc-macros

I am building a small HTML parser in Rust using `syn` and `proc_macro2`.
I have made it so far that i can parse regular HTML tags and it's attributes
So for example

```
html!(
 <div>
   <image></image>
 </div>
)
```

Works

But i would like to parse some `JSX` style code aswell, so something like this

```
html!(
 <div>
     {
      (0..3).map(|| html!(<text value="new"></text>))
     } 
 </div>
)
```

Here is my problem, i can't figure out how to parse the code between the brackets inside my macro_code, i would like to get `Vector` with just `<text></text>` elements.

Here is a playground example

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d0a899ee52772565d4043fea24d8f21d

Comment: Hey, how are you even able to use `html!(..)` instead of `html! { .. }` with proc macros? Don't proc macros always have to be wrapped in braces and not in parens?

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured out an answer for my problem and decided to share it, for anyone else struggling with it too.

It's super easy if you understand the concept of what an expression means in macro.
the whole code between `{}` is an `expression` and when returning the macro result,
you can use it as value inside tokens.

Small example

```
impl ToTokens for Response {
fn to_tokens(&self, tokens: &mut TokenStream) {
    let expressions: Vec<Expr> = self.expressions.clone();
    let entries: Vec<u16> = self.values.clone();

    //We can now use our saved numbers and expressions in this quote! and return something totally new to the user.
    tokens.extend(quote! {
       {
            let mut data: Vec<u16> = vec!(#(#entries),*);
            let expressions: Vec<Vec<u16>> = vec!(#(#expressions),*);
            for expr in expressions {
                data.extend(expr);
            };
           data.iter().fold(0, |acc, len| acc + len )
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you share you final result?  I'm trying to do the same thing but I'm getting stuck.

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of `syn` crate (2+) there is a number of macros that will help parse the content of group enclosed by symbols, like:

- `{}` - `syn::braced`
- `[]` - `syn::bracketed`
- `()` - `syn::parenthesized`

It's pretty straightforward to use as shown in [syn doc examples](https://docs.rs/syn/2.0.31/syn/macro.braced.html)